# When is the best time to do farmer's walking?

Tags: warm-up

When is the best time to do farmer's walking?

Can it serve as a warm-up exercise before squat or bench press?

Comment: Depends what you're trying to accomplish with the farmer's walk. I'd say it's a big exercise onto itself. I wouldn't fry my nervous system with a compound exercise before another like that, if you're looking to make headway on your bench/squat.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The beauty of the farmer's walk is its simplicity. You can add it to any training program and make the program better. I'll do some version of a loaded carry at the end of every strength training workout.

Here's an example of how they could be built into a program:

Day 1 – Push Day. Add one set of standard farmer's walks.

Day 2 – Pull Day. Add one set of single-arm farmer's walks.

Day 3 – Leg Day. Add one set of uneven farmer's walks, a different weight in each hand.

The goal every week is to increase load or duration of the set.

Week 1 – Walk 25 feet up and back 3 times

Week 2 – Walk 30 feet up and back 3 times

Week 3 – Increase the weight and walk 25 feet

Week 4 – Walk 30 feet with the heavier weight

Be sure to note your numbers and your distance and try to improve on it weekly.

Every week I rotate the type of farmer's carry, alternating from handles to kettlebells to fat-grip dumbbells. Training variety is endless. However, the key to success in the farmer's walk is not in the walking, but how you walk with the weight.

In conclusion it is not the best warm up exercise there are other exercises way better for warming up but that also depends on the program you are following.If you are doing powerlifting you won't warm up with farmer's walk.